# How to reshape image from (n,m,4) to (n,m,3) in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an image value like the following:

```
A = [[[  7,  23,   0, 255],
         [ 14,  25,   1, 255],
         [ 23,  26,   1, 255],
         [ 49,  41,  33, 255],
         [ 43,  37,  30, 255],
         [ 42,  33,  25, 255]],

        [[ 59,  69,  59, 255],
         [ 77,  83,  72, 255],
         [ 86,  91,  84, 255],
         [ 16,  16,   8, 255],
         [  9,   7,   2, 255],
         [  1,   0,   0, 255]]]

print(np.array(A).shape) ## (3,6,4)
```

I want to reshape it like `(3,6,3)` such that I want to skip `255` for the matrix.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need slicing not reshape which keeps all elements but changes the shape of the array; For your case, simply drop the last element along the third axis:

```
np.array(A)[:,:,:-1].shape
# (2, 6, 3)
```